# Can I expose multiple containers on the same IP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple web server that listens on port 8080 (node.js app). That server goes inside a container. I can't have more than a few of these servers fit on a machine, because they allocate a lot of memory.

I want to deploy multiple instances of that container (say around 100, maybe more) and then have them be exposed on the same externally visible IP address, at different ports. So say ip_address:10314, ip_address:12605, ip_address:23040, etc.

Can this kind of thing be architected in Kubernetes?

Comment: You have one IP per pod. Each container within can expose ports on the same IP as long as they don't have some conflict with each other. For multi-container pods, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container/

Comment: I added one extra requirement : the servers use a good amount of memory (say 500MB each).
Also, the IPs that pods are running on are not visible externally (from the Internet), right?

Comment: I misread your earlier question. It looks like you want a service of type LoadBalancer which talks to pods. I'm not sure why you'd want to have separate ports for each web server when you could instead have and L3/L7 load balancer which knows to load balance between your instances.

Comment: See https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-applications/

Comment: I need to have separate ports, because each server will be serving something used by a different user. Imagine a system in which users are learning how to use Linux and each container has one pod that's running an app that exposes a terminal as a web application (for example, wetty).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Service of type LoadBalancer in front of each Pod and one container per Pod. Then you want to control the `nodePort` like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-001
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    nodePort: 31001
  selector:
    app: pod-001
```

The `nodePort` is exposed on every node and should work the way you expect it.

Scaling up would then require you to create a new Service+(Deployment)+Pod+Container combination and you'd have to manually make sure that the `nodePort` doesn`t collide with other services.

Cheers

Comment: I think the service by itself a ingress load balancer. Say, I have a deployment with pod details and replica-set set to 100. Now I am just exposing the service to node port. Dont this service automatically load balances the incoming traffic without usng an load balancer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NodePort` service to expose the containers, if you don't need the service to also provide load balancing (which it sounds like you don't). Here's an example YAML config for `NodePort`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service-name
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31112
  selector:
    run: name-of-app
```

(If you want to expose an app that runs on a port other than 80 inside the container, change `port` and `targetPort`.)

Rather than hard-coding everything, you could use an automated build tool, or a set of shell scripts, to automatically populate the `nodePort` and `run` fields. This could let you avoid port collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a reverse proxy such as Nginx. It can work as a frontend for all your containers. All the requests will be sent to the Nginx which will forward them to the containers depending on the port, host name or url of the incoming request